# Unable to achieve loop function using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

The Requirement is to send an email Reminder every 2 days until status is `Completed`, Due Date Reminder and Today Reminder for the `Completion Date`.

- **Due Date Reminder**: 2 days before `Target Date`
- **Today Reminder**: `Completion Date` is equal to `Target Date`
- **Reminder**: Every 2 days until status is `Completed`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a workflow with the following logic and have this trigger on item creation and when item is modified.

Add a column to the list called "Due Date Reminder Email"

If **Due Date Reminder** equals **Today**,
**Send Email** to (Relevant person)
Then update **Due Date Reminder Email** to value "sent"

Else
If **Due Date Reminder** Does not equal **Today**
Update **Due Date Reminder Email** to value "Pending"

*(Logic here is that the update will trigger the workflow again due to being set to trigger when item is modified)*

If **Target Date** equals **Today** 
and if **Completion Date** Not equals **Today**,
**Send Email** to

This may need tweaking slightly but this is going off my assumptions for the way you have your columns set up. This will also send the reminder daily rather than every other day. Hopefully this helps or gives you a decent starting point at least.